# Thinnest part of a 3D shape formed of tessellations

Tags: math, graphics, geometry, tesselation

I have a group of tessellations forming a 3D shape and I need to find the section(s) with least cross section radius in it

Following is the visual aid for understanding this problem:

[Assume that each rectangle in the A,B and C is a tessellation and this diagram is 3D](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwaY1.jpg)

Now, Assume that each rectangle in the A,B and C is a tessellation and this diagram is 3D.

I wish to find 'C' ie.. set of tessellations with least cross section radii or thinnest part of the given shape.

How do I find it? I was thinking of finding the faces closest to each other but that will fetch the tessellations inside the shape as well.

I have tried:
1. Finding convex hull (Doesnt give points in thinnest area)
2. Alpha shape (No way to find the faces on the surface)

I would appreciate any advise on this matter.

Thanks

Comment: You might be looking for the [shape diameter function](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.75.3722&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

Comment: Thank you for the reply but it says unknown link. I looked it up on google and trying it out. Will comment here if that works.

Comment: Try [this link](https://iww.inria.fr/sed-sophia/files/2016/07/Consistent-mesh-skeletonisation.pdf) instead. There are multiple follow-up publications about SDF, mostly about how to compute it fast.